# How to know which Stored procedure is calling the target procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, sybase

I have a stored procedure called `proc1` . Now I have several stored procedures which can call `proc1` . I want to write a query which will return me all the procedures that are calling this `proc1` procedure . I think I need to use `sys.objects` and `sys.sysdepends` to do it . But till now I have been unable to figure it out . Any help will be deeply appreciated .

Comment: sp_depends would help you, give me any example of what your are doing so I cal help you

Answer (score 2):

Try this query

```
select distinct object_name(id)
from syscomments 
where texttype = 0 
and text like '%Proc1%'
and object_name(id) <> 'Proc1'
```

It will find all procedures with `Proc1` text so if you have procedure with comment with word `Proc1` it will be returned too.

Comment: Thanks. Let me check that .